# Local and Shared Repository

Tags: qtp

Can any one tell me if a script has a local repository and also uses a shared repository, which repository will QTP use first when searching for an object during playback?

Answer (score 2):

The Local Object Repository (LOR) is always first to be considered, if an object isn't present in the LOR then all the associated Shared Object Repositories (SOR) are searched in order and you can control the order in which they are searched via the action properties dialog (in the *Associated Repositories* tab).

[image: Associated Repositories]

The objects of all repositories are merged so if there is a duplicate object (by type and name) it will appear from the higher priority repository and you can have an object from one repository appear as the child of an object from another repository.

For example consider the following repositories.

1. **Local:** `Browser("Google").Page("Google").Link("+You")`
2. **sor1.tsr:** `Browser("Google+").Page("Google+").WebEdit("Email")`
3. **sor.tsr:**  `Browser("Google+").Page("Google+").WebEdit("Passwd")`

In this case the `Browser` and `Page` from **sor1** will hide those of **sor** and you can tell where each object originates by looking at the **Repository** field in the Object Repository Editor.

[image: Object Repositry Editor]